# Ionic 3 display data directory image

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I'm having issues displaying a image that is saved in my app directory.

In this part of the code I'm checking if my data directory has files, and if so get their name and save them to an array which i display in the view.

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  file.listDir(this.file.dataDirectory,'').then((result)=>{

    for(let file of result){ //list of all files and directories

      if(file.isDirectory == true && file.name !='.' && file.name !='..'){

      }else if(file.isFile == true){
        this.items.push({
          title: this.fileDirectory+file.name //full path to file
        });

      }
    }
  });
});
```

I did a `checkFile(path, file)` and it did return ***true*** for the given path and file (image) i was trying to display.

This is the code in my view:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="openFile(item.title)">
    <p>{{item.title}}</p>
    <img [src]="item.title"/>
</ion-item>
```

I have only one file downloaded (called ivan.jpg) in that folder for testing purposes. When I try to display the image i only get a broken image icon.

The path which is inserted with `item.title` is:

*file:///data/user/0/com.javorovic.comodo/files/ivan.jpg*

As I said, the file seems to exist but I can't display it in my view, I've been searching for an answer but can't seem to find it.

I've also tried adding `<allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />` to my config.xml

Comment: Hey Ivan do you see what error message is there? 404? did you check if this is a angular sanitization for resourceURLs?

Comment: I get the following error: Not allowed to load local resource: file:///data/user/0/com.javorovic.comodo/files/ivan.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved it by doing the following:

**uninstall webview**

```
ionic cordova plugins rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

**install old one:**

```
ionic cordova plugins add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```

**clean cordova**

```
cordova clean android
```

**[SOURCE](https://github.com/zyra/ionic-image-loader/issues/183)**